# Install RPi module on Pycharm

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I've been using IDLE with my raspberry for a while, it's nice at the beginning, but **Pycharm** provides lots more of features and I'm used to them since I've been also using Android Studio.

The problem is I couldn't figure out how to install the **RPi module** to control the pins of my Raspberry. Does anyone know how to do this?

In case it matters, it's python3 on a raspberry 2B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way of installing it on your desktop but PyCharm has a remote programming feature that allows you to use the PyCharm interface through an ssh connection to your Raspberry Pi. See this [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-development-on-raspberry-pi.html) from Jetbrains.

Comment: Great thanks! I actually followed this one https://www.nathanpjones.com/wp/2016/02/remote-debug-gpio-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: The tutorial link in the answer is dead :(

Comment: The link is no more active

Comment: @LalitVerma I updated the link to a tutorial on the Jetbrains website. Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

You can run Pycharm directly on your Raspberry Pi:
- Using your Raspberry Pi, download the installation file directly from the Pycharm website (JetBrains).  It will be a tarball, i.e., a file ending in ".tar.gz".
- Extract the file to a folder of your choice.
- Browsing through the extracted files and folders, you will find a folder named "bin". Inside "bin" you will find a file named Pycharm.sh
- Using your terminal window, go to the "bin" folder and launch the Pycharm application by typing:  sudo ./Pycharm.sh
After several seconds (it's a little slow to load on my RPi3), Pycharm will load.  Have fun!